# How to select checkboxes that are visible?

Tags: jquery

In my app, the users can dynamically search a database and then select the return results. Right now, I'm able to search the database with jquery and select the rows. The problem I'm facing is that when I search the database and select the rows, it will select all the rows instead of only selecting the rows returned by the search query. So if you search for Germany, you should only be able to select two rows. On the surface it appears as if it will only select two rows, but when logging in the console log, it shows that it selected ALL rows even if they are not shown in the result.

How  do I only select the checkboxes that are showing in the search result?

Here's the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/szkv74m1/

```js
   /*
   * 
   * 
   * 
   * 
   * SELECT PROSPECTS THAT ARE VISIBLE
   * 
   * 
   * 
   */
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var clicked = false;
  $(document).on('click', '.select-click-all', function(){
        
          $(".devprospectcheckbox").prop("checked", !clicked);
            clicked = !clicked;
  
    });
    
      /*
   * 
   * 
   * 
   * 
   * SEARCH PROSPECT IN TABLE
   
   * 
   * 
   */

var $rows = $('#myTable tr')
$('#search_term').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
    });
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn select-click-all btn-primary">Select/Unselect all</button>
   <input id="search_term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by city, country,industry,etc...">
    
<br><br>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
   <th style="width:10%;">#</th>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="4"></td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What console log are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean the "Select/unselect all" button should only select the visible ones?

Comment: @Barmar: yes exactly the select button should only select the visible ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:visible` modifier in the selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicked = false;
  $(document).on('click', '.select-click-all', function() {
    $(".devprospectcheckbox:visible").prop("checked", !clicked);
    clicked = !clicked;

  });

  var $rows = $('#myTable tr')
  $('#search_term').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn select-click-all btn-primary">Select/Unselect all</button>
<input id="search_term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by city, country,industry,etc...">

<br><br>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">#</th>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="devprospectcheckbox" class="devprospectcheckbox" value="4"></td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Haha so simple! Thanks :D